# CRUD with 3-layered architecture; must I triplicate everything?

Tags: .net, wpf, 3-tier

I am working on a new [three-layered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx) .net/WPF application. The application will do a lot more than just [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete), but it does CRUD too. I'm finding that there's a ton of redundant work that needs to be done when setting up a new CRUDdy entity; say, a `Person`:

- In the data access assembly, create a `PersonDocument` class that is structured and marked up with attributes in a way that allows our in-house document storage system to persist it
- But I don't want to expose `PersonDocument` to the upper layers since that would leak information about the persistence mechanism. So the DAL also needs a public `IPerson` and code to adapt a `PersonDocument` into an `IPerson`
- The DAL needs to expose a `PersonRepository` so the upper layers can do CRUDs with `IPerson`s
- The business layer needs to provide information about persons to the presentation layer, but the presentation layer isn't supposed to know about the data access layers or it types. So the BL assembly needs its own `IPerson`. This is probably not exactly like the DAL `IPerson`--in particular, the DAL `IPerson` is going to be almost 100% anemic (data only), while the BL `IPerson` will contain a bunch of operations relating to the business actions you might want to take with a person. But it will be pretty close, and with some simple entities, perhaps exactly the same.
- More mapping code will be needed to go back and forth between a DAL `IPerson` and a BL `IPerson`
- The BL will need its own `PersonRepository` over BL `IPerson`s for use by the presentation layer

Now imagine that I decide I want to start tracking the age of every person I store. I'll need to:

1. Add an age property to the DAL's person document
2. Add an age property to the DAL's `IPerson` and its implementation(s)
3. Update the code that translates a `PersonDocument` into a DAL `IPerson`
4. Update the code that translates a DAL `IPerson` into a `PersonDocument`
5. Add an age property to the BL `IPerson` and its implementation(s)
6. Update the code that translates a DAL `IPerson` into a BL `IPerson`
7. Update the code that translates a BL `IPerson` into a DAL `IPerson`
8. Finally, I can update the databindings in presentation to display age

Something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) could maybe ease the pain in 3, 4, 6, and 7 if I invest the time to learn to use it, but the amount of work involved here still seems to be telling me I have a bad design. Is this just the way it goes with 3-layer architecture, or am I missing the point?

Comment: This feels like exactly the sort of whiteboard question that would fit really well at Programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Before deciding on such a complicated architecture you probably should formulate exactly the benefits that you are going to derive from it. For example, what benefit will it bring you that the UI layer does not reference the DAL? The DAL is *not* meant to be replaced.

Comment: @usr It allows us to deploy business/data on one tier and the UI on another, as will be necessary when/if the word comes down that a mobile version of the app is needed

Comment: @Tragedian when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, whilst being a good question, it is a **software design** problem rather than a programming problem.

Comment: @Tragedian actually the right thing would be to contact a moderator and ask him to move it